# How to extend a variable only if provided

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component that I usually instantiate with `Option | string | null`:

```
AutoCompleteProps<Option | string | null>
```

But I want the component to also accept a type variable, that if passed, extends Option.

This is wrong:

```
export const AutoComplete = <T extends Option | string | null>({
  options,
  label,
  onChange,
}: AutoCompleteProps<T>) => {
```

Because I extend either Option or string or null, I want to only extend Option if a type variable was passed, and if not, just use `Option | string | null`.
What is the correct syntax for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
type AutoCompleteProps<
    T extends Option | UseDefault = UseDefault
> = {
    props:
        T extends UseDefault
            ? Option | string | null
            : T
}
```

Here `T` extends the constraint you want unioned with some other private internal type named `UseDefault`. `UseDefault` is also the default type of the generic `T`. `UseDefault` would be a type that cannot be matched from the outside, or is at least very unlikely to be.

Then where you need to use `T` you have a conditional type that checks for the default type, and swaps in your wider type for the generic. But if `T` is anything besides that default, then it must extend `Option` and can be directly used.

For the `UseDefault` type, I'd suggest a symbol, because they are unique at the type level and so won't clash with any potential values that could be passed in.

```
const useDefault = Symbol('useDefault')
type UseDefault = typeof useDefault
```

But you could use anything that isn't a subtype of `Option | string | null`. This would also work:

```
type UseDefault = { __useDefault__: true }
```

---

Now assuming your `Option` type is something like this:

```
type Option = { option: string }
```

Then this should work like you want:

```
type A = AutoCompleteProps
// { props: string | Option | null }

type B = AutoCompleteProps<{ option: 'literal' }>
// { props: { option: 'literal' } }

type C = AutoCompleteProps<'bad type'> // type error
type D = AutoCompleteProps<null> // type error
type E = AutoCompleteProps<Option | string | null> // type error
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/FAFwngDgpgBA8hEBLA9gOxgXhgbxixVNALhgGcQAnJNAcxgF9hgBjdCmAVzKgBEoAZgENOAGxBYYAZTABbAEYpRACgDk3PoJHjVASlCRYAVR79hYidnDQUArqa0Xm12AEFOIFAGEUsiKKgQKAAFSgIyAB5gGBiYABUYKAAPILQAEzJ4QnQYAB8YE01zcUlCs20QYAA+SRxo2IgwiDJietjYhOTUjIKHYsr2wdiAfizkHPyKajo8mDQxUTah2NI44CZnQxhXSXdPHz8AoNDw4AB6M9iAPWHN6BgAIV2Pb19-QJCmyLwCcZIYVSiJBBShCUSqRhVc6XGI3O6wLzPfZvI6fcIRVTyIRpGAuVRQlwwXhI16HD4nZoReaiUQErYAURJB3exy+EQQf1mUxo9Hy1NpQA)

---

Then you could maybe clean that up with an `OrDefault` type alias:

```
const useDefault = Symbol('useDefault')
type UseDefault = typeof useDefault
type OrDefault<T, TDefault> = T extends UseDefault ? TDefault : T

type AutoCompleteProps<T extends Option | UseDefault = UseDefault> = {
  props: OrDefault<T, Option | string | null>
}
```

Which I think reads pretty nicely.

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#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)